# python maximum minimum code problem without using builtin function

Tags: python, python-3.7

### Heading ##The code is:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        vt = int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    if largest is None:
        largest = vt
    elif vt > largest:
        largest = vt
        print("Maximum is",largest)
    elif smallest is None:
        smallest = vt
    elif vt < smallest:
        smallest = vt
        print("Minimum is",smallest)
```

It only gives output like : Invalid input and maximum is 10, why it can't generate a minimum number, can anyone help me with the problem, please

Comment: Could you please format your code with proper indentation? Also what's the input you tried giving?

Comment: `elif smallest is None:` may be like `if smallest is None:`

Comment: Your both `print` statement must be out side the `if` block

Answer (score 1):

I your code you use [elif](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) so at time only one block is executed.

You print statement is inside the if block so it only executed if condition is true. that's why it print only *Invalid input and maximum is 10*

Try below code:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        vt = int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    if largest is None:
        largest = vt
    elif vt > largest:
        largest = vt
    print("Maximum is",largest)   
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = vt
    elif vt < smallest:
        smallest = vt
    print("Minimum is",smallest)
```

Comment: I tries this one and it doesn't show desired output

Comment: Pls update your questions with sample I/p and desired o/p so more easy to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

print should be written outside to get the final value.one possible answer.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
  num = input("Enter a number: ")
  if num == "done":
    break
  try:
    vt = int(num)
  except:
    print("Invalid input")
    continue
  if largest is None:
    largest = vt
  elif vt > largest:
    largest = vt
    #print("Maximum is",largest)
  if smallest is None:
    smallest = vt
  elif vt < smallest:
    smallest = vt
    #print("Minimum is",smallest) 

 print("Maximum is",largest)
 print("Minimum is",smallest)
```